# Updating R documentation, NAMESPACE and DESCRIPTION files automatically when code is pushed to github

Tags: r, github, rstudio, teamcity

I need to know if I can run `devtools::document()` and `roxygen2::roxygenise()` commands automatically in RStudio or in Teamcity whenever a push is made to github rather than running these commands manually before pushing every time. How can this be done ?

Answer (score 1):

I could be done by a `.git/hooks/pre-commit` script that run : `R -e 'devtools::document()'`. Search on the web for pre-commit hooks. Once your hook is set-up, commit via any interface (Rstudio or anything else) will automaticaly use it. You could configure the script to return an error if any error happends in `devtools::document()`, preventing the code from being commited.

Remark that running devtools::document() is usualy enough, the second roxygen2::roxygenise() command is normaly not needed !

Finaly, i strongly advice not to do it : It is sanity in your coding workflow to document the package before committing it : it might remind you of something you forgot to do.

Answer (score 0):

The [pre-commit frameworks](https://pre-commit.com) supports various types of hooks, e.g. on commit or push, merge, etc. There is an R package {precommit} (disclosure: I am the maintainer) that implements various hooks, among them a [`roxygenize`](https://lorenzwalthert.github.io/precommit/dev/articles/available-hooks.html#roxygenize-1) hook. You can easily set things up with `precommit::use_precommit()` and then adapt `.pre-commit-config.yaml`:

```yaml
-   repo: https://github.com/lorenzwalthert/precommit
    rev: v0.2.0
    hooks:
    -   id: roxygenize
        additional_dependencies:
        -  a.dependency.here
        stages: [commit, push]
```

The `additional_dependencies` can be generated with `precommit::snippet_generate('additional-deps-roxygenize')`. Optionally, starting with version 0.2.0, you can configure GitHub Actions or pre-commit.ci as a contiuous integration service to enforce hooks and auto-fix simple problems (like running roxygen) as described in the [vignette](https://lorenzwalthert.github.io/precommit/dev/articles/ci.html).